Unity Character Controller unclear movement on an inclined plane
I move player using CharacterController in the Vector3(0, -1, 1) direction, which is the opposite of the inclined (45 degrees) plane normal. So, I think character should just stand at the same position. But it moves in the Vector3(0, 1, 1) direction. Could someone please explain why? Is it something with collision?
The code:
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController _controller;
    
    void Start()
    {
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3(0, -1, 1);
        _controller.Move(dir * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        
        Debug.Log($"Dir: {dir}, Vel: {_controller.velocity}");
        Vector3 origin = transform.position + transform.right;
        DebugExt.DrawColored(Color.red).Vector(origin , dir * 2);
    }
}




I've been changing different CC parameters, nothing changed

Move should be called from Update, not FixedUpdate.  Change the delta time accordingly as well.

Id argue that the controller only sees it as a 45 degree angel, therefor going "up" the slope would be 0,1,1 perhaps because 1 up, 1 over..

@hijinxbassist Tried it, same thing

@BugFinder, yeah, i think i got it. The deal is that CC already applies normal to motion, that is why it moves this way

The thing is that CC by itself processes and changes the movement according to the plane angle.
So to make Character stand still on the inclined plane(45d) the motion Vector just should be (0, -1, 0). To make it move forward (parallel to the plane) just set motion Vector to (0, 0, 1).
Oh, and i think it's strange, but it does nothing with normalization. So if u move character forward on the plane, it's velocity will be (0, 1, 1) (magnitude - sqrt(2))
examples
